# Windows advapi.dll referencing non existing dll

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, libavformat

I am using `Java JNI` to load `native dll` module (`64 bit JVM, 64 bit dll, Windows 8.1`). Module is used to decode `H.264` file into byte array using `libavcodec`, which is in precompiled shared dlls.

When I played around in plain JNI (passing `String` to JNI and return `byte[]` back), I had no problem loading my DLL module.  But when I added reference to `avformat.dll`, my dll won´t load causing `unsatisfied link error: Can´t find dependant libraries`.

I scoped `avformat` using `DependencyWalker`. It depends on `advapi.dll` which depends on several dlls reporting as missing. On of them is `API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL`. This dll is really missing on my Win installation.

So, now I am confused about 2 things:

1, Why does MS provided `advapi.dll` depend on dll which is not part of the system?.

2, When I previously tried using `avformat` library in form of standalone Win32 app (exe), `DependencyWalker` reported the same missing dlls, but it executed decoded frames without any problem. How is this possible if I am missing its dependency?

Comment: There are two builds of depends.exe, One for 32bit, one for 64bit. Are you sure you are using the right one? Both open the DLL, but only the right one reports the missing dependency properly.

Comment: I tried both versions, with same missing dlls.

Comment: Are you sure all your dlls (yours and ffmpeg's) have little "64" icon on the left of the entry in D.W. ? Maybe you are mixing 64bit Java with 32-bit ffmpeg.